# How can I access to appdata for writing and reading?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.forms to making a cross-platform app and I need to write in a local directory for saving data.Through my research, i found that it's not the same way to do that in iOS and Android. I've tried something but it doesn't work :

```
public string ReadData()
    {
        string filePath = Path.Combine(
       Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
       "Data.txt");
        var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        return data;
    }

    public void WriteData(string data)
    {
        string filepath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),"Data.txt");
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, data);
    }
```

I get this error :

```
`System.Environment' does not contain a definition for `GetFolderPath'
```

and :

```
The type or namespace `File' does not exist in the namespace `System.IO'.
```

Thank in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to check this bit in the [Xamarin.Forms documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/#Loading_and_Saving_Files)

You're going to have to use a platform specific implementation through the [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) (assuming that you are using a PCL for your shared code).

Taken from the documentation pages: in your shared PCL code create an abstraction in the form of a `Interface` for example like this, if you want to write and load to and from a text file:

```
public interface ISaveAndLoad {
    void SaveText (string filename, string text);
    string LoadText (string filename);
}
```

Now for Android and iOS the documentation specify that you can create the same implementation (which would implicate you could to it directly from you shared code. You should experiment with that).

Note: you still need to create a implementation per platform, this allows you to tweak the implementation per platform as well.

```
[assembly: Dependency (typeof (SaveAndLoad))]
namespace WorkingWithFiles {
    public class SaveAndLoad : ISaveAndLoad {
        public void SaveText (string filename, string text) {
            var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var filePath = Path.Combine (documentsPath, filename);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText (filePath, text);
        }
        public string LoadText (string filename) {
            var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var filePath = Path.Combine (documentsPath, filename);
            return System.IO.File.ReadAllText (filePath);
        }
    }
}
```